# Laravel Flash Message- show unescaped html that has been set from Voyager admin panel

Tags: laravel, session, flash-message, voyager

```
    // session()->flash("message", "{{ setting('site.contact_success_msg') }}"); //doesn't work
    // session()->flash('message', 'Thank you so much for your feedback.'); //works.
    session()->flash('message', {!! setting('site.contact_success_msg') !!});//doesn't work
```

I am trying to show a flash message to the user. I have set the message from **Voyager**, using **Rich text editor** to output something like:

> **Success!** Thank you so much for your feedback.

But the above code shows this error message:

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError thrown with message "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'"

Stacktrace:

## 0 Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\app\Http\Controllers\FeedbackController.php:85

Could anyone please help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've got it. I used the following code:

```
session()->flash('message', setting('site.contact_success_msg'));
```

And then where I flashed the message, I used:

```
$flash = session('message')
```

and then showed the output message where I needed using:

```
{!! $flash !!}
```

instead of:

```
{{ $flash }}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution.

Comment: Yep. You don't need the `{{` stuff in the `session()->...` bit because it's already PHP.